# Parse javac compilation errors

Tags: java, parsing, javac

I have done lots of looking around and can't seem to find an existing library for parsing javac compilation errors. I am considering implementing a "javac error parser" myself but I can foresee that it probably won't be straight forwards (lots of bits to consider).

I am not using ant for building (There are many reasons for this), but I can collect the output of javac like this:

```
Something.java:1: error: Something is not abstract and does not override abstract method foo(boolean) in InterfaceSomething
public class Something implements InterfaceSomething{
       ^
Something.java:49: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Something[]
        return baz;
               ^
Something.java:55: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Something[]
        return baz;
               ^
Note: Something.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors
```

Ideally I would like an object which holds a list of "Errors". Each "Error" has a filename, line number, description and code snippet.

For example, in this case error 0 would hold:

```
A String filename = "Something.java"
An int lineNum = 1
A String description = "Something is not abstract and....."
A String codeSnippet ="public class Something implements InterfaceSomething{"
```

Having attempted parsing in the past of lots of things, I realise it's often quite a big job as there will always be some case where the output is slightly different or not expected (hence I am looking for a library where someone has spent a fair bit of time considering those situations to save me reinventing the wheel).

It seems awfully odd that I can't find this. Any ideas?

EDIT: Important - I am not asking anyone to do this for me, I am perfectly capable of doing it myself, I am just wanting any ideas or suggestions about anything which already exists which does this. I'm not after answers including code, but perhaps answers suggesting the formatting rules for this output, or directing me to some existing library I haven't been able to find.

Comment: I am not having problems with compiling, this question is regarding parsing the output from javac. The compile errors above are on purpose as an example of javac output when there are errors causing the compilation to fail. Something.java and InterfaceSomething.java are made up classes that do not exist, just like baz and foo. (this comment was in response to another comment which now seems deleted)

Comment: I'm extremely confused how this question can be deemed "too broad". It's very specific, I want something (preferably java) for parsing javac output, does it exist already? Can one of the close voters please explain what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and [`Diagnostic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/Diagnostic.html) classes are something you want to check.

Here is some code from one of my early projects

```
public String compile(String source, Object... options) {
    String className = getMainClassName(source);

    if (className == null) {
        throw new WrongSourceStructureException("No public class which implements 'Solution'");
    }

    javax.tools.JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    if (compiler == null)
        throw new BadEnvironmentException("You should specify path to JDK in your JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME");

    Writer err = new StringWriter();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    List<String> compilerOptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] opts = new String[options.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(options, 1, opts, 0, opts.length);

    if (options != null) {
        compilerOptions.addAll(Arrays.asList(opts));
    }

    compilerOptions.add("-d");
    compilerOptions.add("./tmp/classes/");

    JavaFileObject codeSolution = new JavaSourceFromString(className, source);

    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> units = Arrays.asList(codeSolution);
    javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(err, null, diagnostics, compilerOptions, null, units);

    boolean success = task.call();

    if (!success) {
        StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
        for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            errorMessages.append(diagnostic.getMessage(null)).append("\n");
        }
        throw new NotCompiledException(errorMessages.toString());
    }

    String aPackage = getPackage(source);

    return ".tmp/classes/" + options[0] + aPackage.replace(".", "/") + "/" + className + ".class";
}
```

Also, there is [commons-jci](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jci/), it may be more clear than standard JavaCompiler.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I knew there would be a little gem like this hidden away somewhere. I'll read up on the javadoc and examples and see what I can do. All I needed was pointing in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: This seems awfully odd:

"If a diagnostic listener is provided, the diagnostics will be supplied to the listener. If no listener is provided, the diagnostics will be formatted in an unspecified format and written to the default output, which is System.err unless otherwise specified. Even if a diagnostic listener is supplied, some diagnostics might not fit in a Diagnostic and will be written to the default output."

Comment: @ThePerson, yeah, you may want to set your own `PrintStream` as `System.err` and `System.out`. I've updated my answer with code sample.